# puppet install non forge module

Tags: puppet

I'm fairly new to puppet and I want to install a puppet module not using the puppet forge.

I have a page similar to the puppet forge where I keep my modules. I have 2 instances one is a Linux server so I can ssh into, and one is can work from remotely.

I have used git clone to make a branch, and I have copied the module i want into a folder inside that branch. How do I install the module into my Linux server?

When I ssh into my linux instance I get this message

```
puppet module list --tree
/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

Comment: So, have you made sure that the module actually ends up in `/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own modules and then use them on your own servers,
follow the guidelines in https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html

In particular the `puppet module generate` is good for getting started with a skeleton.  Use the files in the skeleton (Modulefile, manifests etc) to build a tar ball then refer to https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_installing.html#installing-from-a-release-tarball to install the tarball